# How to view files in bare repositories?

Tags: git, git-bare, git-show

I have a bare repository in my remote. I want to look at files, that is open in an editor and view the code.
For listing files, git ls-files master or git ls-tree master.
and for viewing single file, I could do git show 100644
But how do I view files in directories. Here is an example:

```
100644 blob 03ec70a7ab513de8d568450dd8fca93987a22da0    .gitignore
100644 blob 75a85b0137fe1ee0c60bda6dcfac78d2d59a1759    README.md
040000 tree 53a58d85bc833575fdfee86058d88a4928c6fe76    templates
```

If I do git show 03ec70, it shows the content of .gitignore file

If I do git show 53a58d, it lists the contents of template folder

```
403.html
404.html
500.html
base.html
```

But How can I open the individual files to see them. Example: base.html in the above case

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
git show ${branch}:templates/base.html
```

Comment: I guess one cannot edit in bare repository. It is read-only rite?

Comment: You can edit all you want, but it's a lot easier to work in a non-bare repo!  If you have access to the bare repo you should clone it, make changes, and push.

Answer (score 7):

If you want more detailed contents of the `templates` folder, you can use `ls-tree` with the tree's ID.  For example:

```
git ls-tree 53a58d
```

Which will show you the full tree entries.  From there, you can `git cat-file blob` or `git show` them.

For example:

```
% git ls-tree HEAD
040000 tree 62711729ee3bd52fd75fa4fdd0944c9890f6a249    .nuget
100644 blob b457310ab0fbab34746e9ded04b378241f9b9fe3    GitClient.sln
040000 tree 197b7190b843ef07e78e6589c6edd84bdcdd4082    packages
```

If I want to look at the subtree `packages`:

```
% git ls-tree 197b719
100644 blob df885643f0a23e0307df2c704f1e21b500185344    repositories.config
```

And if I want to look at the contents of `packages/repositories.config` at HEAD:

```
% git cat-file blob df88564
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...etc...
```